# Setting Struts2 Action members from jsp 

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have a html form with action attribute pointing to struts action

Here is a JSP

```
<s:select name="roleId" id="roleId" list="roleMap" headerKey=""
                        headerValue="SELECT" theme="simple" value="%{roleId}" cssClass="dropdown_menu"></s:select>
```

It generates html like

```
<select name="roleId" id="roleId" class="dropdown_menu">
    <option value=""
    >SELECT</option>
    <option value="11">User</option>
    <option value="9">Administrator</option>


</select>
```

I have an action with getters  and setters

```
//
//
//
private String roleId;
//
//
public String getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleRId(String roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }
//
//
//
```

And the validation:

```
<field name="roleId">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message key="USER.ROLE_ERR" />
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

But for some reason roleId property is not setting and it always gives me error saying role must be specified. When I disable the validation action receives all  properties except `roleId` , What can be the proble , How do I detect such kind of errors?,

I am using Struts 2.0, Windows 7 , eclipse Ganimid and Tomcat 6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setRoleRId` is misspelled (should be `setRoleId`)

Unless you misspelled it when copying it here.

Always use Eclipse getters/setters generators.

And, BTW(not related to your problem), perhaps you should better use an Integer for the `roleId` field, Struts2 can convert query parameters quite decently (in contrast with Struts1) to other types than String.